# NSUrl(Audio URL ) convert into NString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsurl

My Code just like this..

```
    NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSError* error;
    NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:recoredAudioUrl usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"recoredAudioUrl %@",myString)
```

It Print `Null` and i also try 
`[recoredAudioUrl absoluteString]` but when i convert this to `NSData` then  it `data.length` also print 0

Comment: looking at your question again, it seems like you are trying to read an audio file as a text file (to an NSString) in this case my answer is irrelevant, you need to read it as data, not as string.

Comment: ` NSData *audiodata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recoredAudioUrl]; ` it works perfectly and i upload on server perfectly   but when i play this url in Broswer it not run :(

Answer (score 1):

You can not read audio file as `NSString`.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 UserInfo=0x100115d70
>   "filename.mp3” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its
>   contents can’t be determined."

Use `NSData`.

```
NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: `NSData *audiodata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recoredAudioUrl]; ` it works perfectly and i upload on server perfectly but when i play this url in Broswer it not run :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your recording URL first. Is it coming NULL? If not then init your string with below method:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:recordingUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```